# How to determine downstream demand from multicast sink

Tags: project-reactor

Is there any way to determine the minimum downstream request among subscribers to a multicast sink? With a regular FluxSink there is requestedFromDownstream() which I can use to implement backpressure, but couldn't figure out any equivalent for Sinks.Many.

I've tried scanning the inners but it doesn't seem to show downstream demand, and the closest I could find is to tryEmitNext - but it seems this may result in messages being dropped for the slow consumers and delivered to others before I detect it.

I could interpose a backpressure buffer, but I'm reading events from a file that is too large to be buffered completely, and I don't want the extra overhead of the buffer stage since the file I'm reading from is itself essentially a buffer. There is a mechanism for modulating the rate at which events are published (simulated time) which I control upstream of the sink, but in addition I want to accommodate letting subscribers catch up if they lag a bit.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FluxSink` can easily provide the downstream request because there is only ever one downstream `Subscriber` (1 sink per subscription in eg. `Flux.create`).

`Sinks.Many` have many flavors with many downstream patterns, most of which allow multiple subscribers to a single sink instance (except with `Sinks.many().unicast()`).

The best option is indeed to `tryEmitNext` and look out for `EmitResult.FAIL_OVERFLOW`.

You need to pick the flavor carefully to avoid the "message is dropped for slow consumers" (I'm guessing you're trying `directBestEffort()`?)

Comment: I see - so if I pick directAllOrNothing() and tryEmitNext() when one (or more) subscribers has no demand, then it will return FAIL_OVERFLOW and if I can sort of push the message back onto my queue, then nothing will be lost and I'll effectively wait for the slowest consumer. Thanks.